# How to sum distinct counts in power bi without applying the distinct count to the whole calculation

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

So, I have this metric:

```
New User =
COALESCE (
    CALCULATE (
        COUNT ( VW_USER_SESSION[USers] ),
        FILTER (
            'VW_USER_SESSION',
            'VW_USER_SESSION'[NEW_USER] = 1
                && VW_USER_SESSION[USER_TYPE] = TRUE
        )
    ),
    0
)
```

When one of the filters called Profile has only one element selected, the value is correct.
However, when I select multiple Profiles, the total is not correct. I belive it's because it applies the distinct count to the whole range of data. But what I want it to do is to sum the results of each distinct count of each profile. And when selecting multiple profiles only sum up those values.

So, imagine distinct count of Profile A has 100 and distinct count Profile B has 100. The total should be 200.However, if client 1 uses Profile A and B, it only counts as 1, instead of 2, which is what we want to see.

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected result…

Comment: [ALLSELECTED](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/allselected-function-dax) ?